# Factor Modelling with PCA

Tags: econometrics

If I am using a Dynamic Factor Modelling (DFM) with PCA (as Stock and Watson) but only as a dimension reduction (I am not using the loading matrix), isn't that absolutely the same as PCA?

Moreover, does the dynamic part of the Factor Model affect only the loading matrix?